# Visual Studio 2022 Crashing when adding a Database or Data Connection

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I started a new Windows Forms App and am trying to add a SQL Server database connection to the app. I'm using the following method: DataSources Window -> Add New Data Source -> Database -> Dataset -> New Connection

Each time I start to enter the Server Name for the new connection, Visual Studio simply freezes and crashes.

Here's a photo of where the crash keeps happening.

[[image: Photo]]

Does anyone know what is causing this or how  to fix it?
I'm rolling back to the 2019 ver. to see if that helps at all.

Seems absurd that I wouldn't be able to add a database connection to a project. I've done it so many times before.

UPDATE: I tried adding a connection string through the application settings. It crashed as soon as I chose Connection String...

[[image: Photo2]]

Comment: It's crashing in the 2019 version too... wth

Comment: You did not specify where the connection was placed. There are several places for this.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I'm doing the following: DataSources Window -> Add New Data Source -> Database -> Dataset -> New Connection

Comment: Are you sure it is not a connection timeout? By default, that is 30 seconds. Did you kill VS before waiting for the connection timeout?

Comment: I didn't kill VS at all. It's been freezing as soon as I start entering a Server Name. Then crashes, might be a timeout... I'll check

Comment: So, even when I manage to enter the Server Name, it crashes when I open the dropdown of databases. The database I want is there, but VS freezes and I cant select it.

Comment: Try a simple test, create an instance of SqlConnection. pass in your connection string then invoke Open. Does it work or do you get an error.

Comment: Well, coding in the SqlConnection with the Connection String and invoking Open, did not through any errors. I'll keep testing to see if any database access throughs any errors. (I still cant use the built-in GUI for adding a database connection...)

Answer (score 0):

You may have disabled/uninstalled the "SQL Server Data Tools - Sql Editor" extension from Extensions -> Manage Extensions -> Installed. If so, enable/reinstall it.